# C# - Convert WPF Image.source to a System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I've found loads of people converting a `BitmapSource` to a `Bitmap`, but what about `ImageSource` to `Bitmap`? I am making an imaging program and I need to extract bitmaps from the image displayed in the `Image` element. Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT 1:

This is a function for converting the `BitmapImage` to a `Bitmap`. Remember to set the 'unsafe' option in the compiler preferences.

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap(BitmapSource srs)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap btm = null;

    int width = srs.PixelWidth;

    int height = srs.PixelHeight;

    int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

    byte[] bits = new byte[height * stride];

    srs.CopyPixels(bits, stride, 0);

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* pB = bits)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(pB);

            btm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr);
        }
    }
    return btm;
}
```

Next is now to get a `BitmapImage`:

```
RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)inkCanvas1.ActualWidth,
    (int)inkCanvas1.ActualHeight,
    96d, 96d,
    PixelFormats.Default);

targetBitmap.Render(inkCanvas1);

MemoryStream mse = new MemoryStream();
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder mem = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
mem.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(targetBitmap));
mem.Save(mse);

mse.Position = 0;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = mse;
bi.EndInit();
```

Next is to convert it:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(BitmapSourceToBitmap(bi));
```

Comment: No. This is just terrible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use unsafe code. There's an overload of `CopyPixels` that accepts an IntPtr:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap2(BitmapSource srs)
{
    int width = srs.PixelWidth;
    int height = srs.PixelHeight;
    int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
        srs.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height * stride, stride);
        using (var btm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr))
        {
            // Clone the bitmap so that we can dispose it and
            // release the unmanaged memory at ptr
            return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(btm);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that internally, this constructor of `Bitmap` calls `GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0`, which expects the user to free the memory when it's no longer required...

Comment: @Cameron, good point. I edited my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, the memory can't be freed until after the System.Drawing.Bitmap is disposed (I can't find any docs on this, but after trying it out in an interop-heavy application, my images only appear properly if I free afterwards, so it doesn't seem like it's copying the data internally). Also, the [GDI docs](http://www.jose.it-berater.org/gdiplus/reference/flatapi/bitmap/gdipcreatebitmapfromscan0.htm) seem to require that stride be a multiple of 4; so `(srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8` should be `(srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32 * 8`, I believe.

Comment: @Cameron - try freezing the bitmap before you clone it.  That _should_ release the hold on memory.

Answer (score 3):

That example worked for me:

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertToBitmap(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        var width = bitmapSource.PixelWidth;
        var height = bitmapSource.PixelHeight;
        var stride = width * ((bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        var memoryBlockPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), memoryBlockPointer, height * stride, stride);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, memoryBlockPointer);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are your ImageSource not a BitmapSource? If your loading the images from files they should be.

Reply to your comment:

Sounds like they should be BitmapSource then, BitmapSource is a subtype of ImageSource. Cast the ImageSource to BitmapSource and follow one of those blogposts.

Comment: No, it says they are ImageSources. I am loading them from BitmapIamges converted from Bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks, i have come up with a method that I believe works fine. I've posted as an edit to my question.

Comment: @SimonStenderBoisen - an `ImageSource` might be from `XAML` file instead of a `Bitmap` file.  If so, its underlying class might be `DrawingBrush` and would need to be converted to get an actual `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `BitmapSourceToBitmap` method at all. Just do the following after creating your memory stream:

```
mem.Position = 0;  
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(mem);
```