# How do I get an image to save after rotation at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, printing, richtextbox

I am working with WPF and I have an application that the user loads an image file into a `RichTextBox` and they can rotate the image and print it. I am not sure as to why the image after it has been rotated will not print as it is displayed on the screen. Instead it prints the original. I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

The following is the code for my application. Code when the retrieve file `Button` is clicked:

```
private void retrieve_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //Retrieve the file or image you are looking for
  OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();

  of.Filter = "Formats|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif;*.ico;*.txt|JPG Image|*.jpg|BMP image|*.bmp|PNG image|*.png|GIF Image|*.gif|Icon|*.ico|Text File|*.txt";

        var dialogResult = of.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {               
                try
                {

                    System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox myRTB = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();                                     
                {
                    Run myRun = new Run();

                    System.Windows.Controls.Image MyImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(of.FileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


                    InlineUIContainer MyUI = new InlineUIContainer();
                    MyUI.Child = MyImage;


                    rotateright_button.IsEnabled = true;
                    print_button.IsEnabled = true;

                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(myRun);
                    paragraph.Inlines.Add(MyUI);

                    FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
                    richTextBox.Document = document;                       
                }
            }

            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid File");
            }

        }
    }
```

When the rotate right button is clicked the following code is executed:

```
    RotateTransform cwRotateTransform;
    private void rotateright_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox.LayoutTransform = cwRotateTransform;

        if (cwRotateTransform == null)
        {
            cwRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
        }

        if (cwRotateTransform.Angle == 360)
        {
            cwRotateTransform.Angle = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cwRotateTransform.Angle += 90;
        }
    }
```

After the `Image` has been loaded and rotated the user can use the following code to print:

```
    private void InvokePrint(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();

            flowDocument = richTextBox.Document;
            flowDocument.ColumnWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
            flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(65);
            IDocumentPaginatorSource iDocPag = flowDocument;

            printDialog.PrintDocument(iDocPag.DocumentPaginator, "Print Document");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: The transformations are performed by the rendering graphics (device context, whatever), not to the source image. If you want to save the transformed image you will need to render the transformaed image to a buffer of appropriate type, and print that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (substitute yourImageControl in the first line, specify which RotateFlipType you want and be sure to reference the System.Drawing dll):

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapSourceToBitmap((BitmapSource)YourImageControl.Source);
bitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

[Another option for conversion...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709472/1418486)

P.S. You would get a better answer in less time if you posted some code and told us more about [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: I hadn't even begun writing any code. What I had researched dealt along the lines of utilizing DrawingVisual, RenderBitmap, and FileStream. I wasn't sure if this was the right direction or not. Thank you for the code I will try it today and let you know the progress I make =)

Comment: _@narohi, I have posted the code for the application. Could your code still be used even though the image is being placed into a container?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by container, but it will work as long as you are able to access the BitmapSource object.

Comment: in order for image files to be displayed with a RichTextBox they have to be placed within a UI container (I could be wrong), but this is the only way I could successfully get the images to display. I will take another look at your code and see what happens as I am still stuck on this issue.