# How to convert System.Windows.Controls.image to System.Drawing.Icon c#

Tags: c#

I have this images

```
var a = new System.Windows.Controls.Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Accounts;component/Resources/close.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
```

and i need to convert it to system.drawing.icon is there a way to do it???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap

Comment: its not image to icon

Comment: I got this link while googling http://www.go4expert.com/articles/convert-image-icon-c-sharp-t19250/