# Convert System.Windows.Media.ImageSource to System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a variable of type `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`. This I have to convert into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I can't find any solution that works for me.

Is it possible to make this behavior work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution for you:

```
public static Drawing.Bitmap GetBitmapFromImageSource(BitmapSource source) {
            int width = source.PixelWidth;
            int height = source.PixelHeight;
            int stride = width * ((source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
                source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height * stride, stride);
                using (var bmp = new Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr)) {
                    return new Drawing.Bitmap(bmp);
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, it is not. This function uses "BitmapSource" and I am not able to convert ImageSource to BitmapSource.

Comment: You just copied the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5709472/495455) and refactored it a little :(

Comment: No! This is my project and I just copied from visual studio that I code before. Maybe it's the same with your source